# "talvez a ti te contassem" é gramaticalmente correto? É aceito apenas coloquialmente? Ou trata-se de licença poética?

Tags: coloquialismos, diferenças-regionais

[**"Ai, se os meus olhos falassem"**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyppko3uIzM), uma antiga - e linda - canção de autoria de Nóbrega E. Souza e Jerônimo Bragança, tem o seguinte trecho:

- Ai se os meus olhos falassem,
- Talvez a ti te contassem,
- O que eu não conto a ninguém.

Ao meu ouvido de falante do pt-BR, "a ti te contassem" soa muito estranho, principalmente na língua falada.  Trata-se de licença poética?  Apenas um coloquialismo?  Ou é aceito como gramaticalmente correto em ambos os lados do Atlântico?

> - [**Licença poética**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licen%C3%A7a_po%C3%A9tica) é uma incorreção de linguagem permitida na poesia. Em sentido mais amplo, são opiniões, afirmações, teorias e situações que não seriam aceitáveis fora do campo da literatura.

Comment: Também me soa estranho. Faria sentido se o "te" fosse o objeto da oração: "talvez contassem a ti de ti" "talvez contassem-te para você".

Comment: Parece-me que é mais uma questão de rimar/métrica. A ordem normal de um redobro seria _talvez te contasse a ti_ (por exemplo, na resposta à pergunta _A quem contarias?_). Também seria possível _a ti, talvez te contasse_. Mas _talvez a ti te contasse_ não me parece.

Comment: Não sei, @Artefacto, a mim parece-me uma maneira natural (mas rara) de acentuar o "a ti": «talvez *a ti* te contasse», por oposição aos outros a quem não contaria.

Comment: @ANeves Não vejo nada de natural. Em outros casos com um constituinte focalizado não podemos retomar o constituinte com um clítico: _a nenhum deles (*lhes) contaria isso_. Portanto, quando muito seria possível sem o _te_, mas não consigo pensar em nenhum contexto em que antepor _a ti_ não gere uma estrutura de topicalização, a qual se escreveria com vírgula a seguir a _ti_ e que sem _talvez_ desencadiaria ênclise.

Comment: @Artefacto Isso é areia demais para a minha camioneta. :) Aceito sem reservas.

Comment: @Artefacto   Independente de estar certo ou errado,  eu me pergunto se o único motivo para o autor ter incluído "a ti" teria sido para manter a métrica. O que achas?

Comment: @Centaurus acho que é isso. E não meteu "a ti" na posição normal, a seguir ao verbo, para poder rimar com o verso anterior.

Comment: As gramáticas normativas costumam chamar isso de objeto pleonástico. No caso, objeto indireto pleonástico. Trata-se de uma figura de linguagem que enfatiza o objeto, como dito na resposta do stafusa.

Comment: @bfavaretto O problema, em minha opinião, não é estar lá tanto _te_ como _a ti_, mas antes o facto de _a ti_ vir antes do verbo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O papel dessa redundância [parece ser](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/eu-te-adorarei-a-ti.1408375/) o de enfatizar o objeto. Acredito que não é estritamente gramático, ou seja, que é coloquialismo ou mesmo licença poética.

Coloquialmente, se não soasse estranho, acredito que seria (mais) aceito, assim como "vou te contar, só pra você" o é.
Uma redundância desse tipo é muito comum na tradução para o português do famoso aforismo do santuário de Delfos:

> Conhece-te a ti mesmo e conhecerás o universo e os deuses.

Essa frase aparece desta forma num [artigo no site da Academia Brasileira de Letras](http://www.academia.org.br/artigos/conhece-te-ti-mesmo), na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conhece_a_ti_mesmo) e em diversos outros texto em pt-BR (e.g., [esse](https://www.significados.com.br/conhece-te-a-ti-mesmo/) e [esse](https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/filosofia/conhece-te-a-ti-mesmo-socrates-e-a-nossa-relacao-com-o-mundo.htm)). Em pt-PT o mais antigo uso que encontrei foi em [um livro de 1839](https://books.google.de/books?id=dDM9AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA342&lpg=PA342&dq=%27%27conhece-te+a+ti+mesmo%22+obliquo&source=bl&ots=6qbT5qF3JY&sig=7VOYrHD6DMhGdRO-sVyk2wmt0wI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi509Lk5d3YAhVF6aQKHZ4LABgQ6AEISjAJ#v=onepage&q=''conhece-te%20a%20ti%20mesmo%22%20obliquo&f=false) (pg. 342) e um [projeto literário](https://helenagmartins.com/category/projeto-literario/) de 2014 foi batizado "Eu a ti, contava-te uma história".

A presença dessa figura num aforismo pode significar que ela já foi mais aceita no passado.

Comment: As construções análogas seriam _talvez te contasse a ti_ e _a ti, talvez te contasse_. _Talvez a ti te contasse_ não me parece encaixar na última construção (uma deslocação à esquerda clítica); "talvez a ti" não funciona como tópico.

Comment: @Artefacto Você se refere ao projeto literário?

Comment: quando falei em construções análogas, referia-me, respetivamente, ao _conhece-te a ti mesmo_ e ao _eu, a ti, contava-te uma história_.

Comment: @Artefacto, ok, mas você vê alguma diferença entre "*talvez te contasse a ti*" e "*talvez a ti te contasse*"? De qualquer forma, pesquisando rapidamente sobre a expressão que você usou no teu primeiro comentário (deslocação clítica), me parece bem possível que me falte base teórica no assunto.

Comment: Coisas como *conhece-te a ti mesmo, curou-se a si mesmo, quem te disse a ti*, etc. são corriqueiras em Portugal, e vêm reconhecidas nas gramáticas. Aliás no português europeu, *conhece a ti mesmo* é que é agramatical. As reticências do @Artefacto são em relação à ordem. A mim não me choca. Naquele contexto, e independentemente da rima, é até a minha ordem preferida. Mas, Artefacto, *nem a mim me contavam, (quanto mais a ti)* tem de estar correto (*a mim, nem me contavam* tem uma interpretação diferente). Não é paralelo a *talvez a ti te contassem*?